A composite calculation
Who discovered the calculation behind this alphametic?
$MAG \cdot MESSAGE = A^{GM} + G$

I didn't include no-computers or ask uniqueness to accept an answer, but would credit those.

The answer is:

 Let M = 6, A = 4, G = 1, E = 7, S = 0, the calculation result of both sides is the fifth Fermat number 4294967297, which was discovered by Euler in 1732. But my way to get these values of each letter was entirely with the help of computer.

